# How to get the exact reason for penalty?

Tags: support, accounts

It is so frustrating to have a quite legitimate question posted on [Is it possible to dispute penalty box or at least to know the reason for being penalized?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366327) and getting it closed unexpectedly without a chance to comment.

Sorry for nagging like this, however the post is locked, so comments are disabled, but I really need to know the reason to LEARN! Please do not close this one too, please be constructive and help me to learn the right way of using this community.

On the closed page @rene suggested I

> respond to the moderator message

but the problem is that I did not receive ANY explanatory message. Otherwise, I would never post [Is it possible to dispute penalty box or at least to know the reason for being penalized?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366327). I would like to stay constructive, but how can I if I don't know anything about why my account was penalized.

Another user suggested it might have happened because of use of team account, but that's just a speculation and I really would like to know the real reason for sure. And if so I'd like to stay corrected, however I do believe users should be given a chance to learn from their mistakes.

Pushing them away like this without giving them the reason they were penalized is so discouraging that I am thinking should I ever come back here again at all. I mean if I did something really evil intentionally then this kind of punishment would be justified, but trying just to be helpful to users and getting punished so harshly like this without giving any explanation is really not fair.

Should moderators send explanatory messages if they penalize accounts? IF yes then where exactly I should be looking for such message as I did not receive anything to my e-mail and also I don't see anything on my profile account? Please just help me out here!

Comment: It's neither closed nor locked. It's been moved to meta.SE.

Comment: But I can not comment there, it says: 
`comments disabled on deleted / locked posts / reviews`

Comment: You don't even have an account there... Create an account on meta.SE with the same credentials and it should automatically link you back as the owner of the question.

Comment: Thank you very much, Mystical. I am new around here and still am learning the right ways. Now I see the page. Sorry. This one can now be closed.

Comment: Just a thing though. You aren't certain the team account thing is the reason. The team account team goes against the ToS. You got banned for rules violation.... I understand why you would like to double check...but if it quacks like a duck....

Comment: Patrice, but in order not to repeat my mistakes I really would like to learn why exactly and what exact rules I violated.

Comment: Using the "not reproducable" close reason on this way would make possible to close around a half of the site... questions about induvidual, specific main site questions should be obviously ontopic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a Stack Exchange issue, not an SO-specific issue.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @Mysticial's explanation I realized I needed to actually join the https://meta.stackexchange.com to be able to see all the comments and to comment myself. So that's why I am posting this answer to summ this page up.

As a side note, the message `comments disabled on deleted / locked posts / reviews` is really not helpful, especially for new users like myself. It could be changed to something like `Create an account on meta.SE to be able to post comments`.